# Regex group generates empty matches among wanted matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn regex. I've created this `/(\d?\.?\d?)/g` to extract all numbers in a comma separated list of float numbers. like this:

```
1,2.2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

https://regex101.com/r/aJ3eF2/2

But this pattern generates empty matches among wanted matches.

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-1]   `1`
MATCH 2
1.  [1-1]   ``
MATCH 3
1.  [2-5]   `2.2`
MATCH 4
1.  [5-5]   ``
```

I want to understand why this happens? and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex to fix this behavior:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

or better using **word boundaries**:

```
(\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ3eF2/3)

Your regex is giving empty matches because your regex `(\d?\.?\d?)` has everything **optional** i.e. a digit and decimal point and digit following it. Also you need to use quantifier `+` to make it match more than one digit on either side of decimal point.

`(?:...)` make it a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not expect something like `.001` use `(\d+\.?\d+)`

Link: https://regex101.com/r/pX7rL1/1